# In Admin if category = x then don't show content tab

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I want to check the **admin** edit article for the category of the article.  Much in the same way fields does.

And if the category is a certain one then don't show the content tab (as I will be using fields instead).

Then I can create custom templates, but it is less confusing for the user.

It needs to change if the category changes so it can't be on initial page load.

Answer (score 3):

Override the `administrator/components/com_content/views/article/edit.php` in your admin template, and then, in the overridden file, create a condition to hide the following code if $this->item->catid = '8' (where 8 is the category ID that you want to hide the `content` table for):

```
<?php if ($this->item->catid != '8') {
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'general')); ?>
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'general', JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_CONTENT')); ?>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span9">
        <fieldset class="adminform">
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('articletext'); ?>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.edit.global', $this); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');
} else{
    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'images')); ?>
}?>
```

If you only want to hide the editor (and the whole `content` tab), then just create the condition around the following code:

```
<fieldset class="adminform">
    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('articletext'); ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Right, this is what I had tried, but the close button stopped working.  I only did it around the admin form bit.  I also wanted to make the category from span3 to span12 as it didn't need to be so small after that instance.  In any case it didn't quite work so I'm going to try Drew G's solution.  But thank you for your answer, it's an honour to have ioctopus answer one of my questions!

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this with a editor-xtd plugin. Instead of having it create/inject a button it'll inject the javascript that does what you're wanting.

Question: the category select field is part of the content tab so if you have the content tab be hidden (for certain categories) then the user will never be able to change that category from inside the article edit page after changing to one of those categories (or the Publish Status, Access level, etc for that matter). So are you wanting to hide the content tab, or just the editor?

**update**

Here is a proof of concept of a plugin-xtd that I believe does what you're wanting. You'd need to change the category IDs in in the $cats variable.

cm_hidecontent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.6" type="plugin" group="editors-xtd" method="upgrade">
    <name>plg_editor-xtd_cm_hidecontent</name>
    <author>Drew G</author>
    <creationDate>Oct 2017</creationDate>
    <copyright>-</copyright>
    <authorEmail>-</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>-</authorUrl>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <description>Proof of concept for hiding the content editor when certain categories are selected.</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="cm_hidecontent">cm_hidecontent.php</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

cm_hidecontent.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * 
 */
class plgButtonCm_hidecontent extends JPlugin
{

    /**
     * Load the language file on instantiation.
     *
     * @var    boolean
     * @since  3.1
     */
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;


    /**
     * Inject the needed javascript
     */
    function onDisplay($name, $asset, $author)
    {

        // List which category IDs you want the editor to hide from.
        // You can pull this data from a plugin parameter or leave it hardcoded
        $cats = json_encode(array(1536, 419));

        $js =
<<<EOF

jQuery(function($){

    jQuery('#jform_catid').change(function()
    {
        checkStatus();
    });

    var checkStatus = function()
    {
        // Need to cast the value to a number else Array.includes() will fail
        var val = Number(jQuery('#jform_catid').val());

        // You could hard code this array.
        var cats = {$cats};

        if(cats.includes(val))
        {
            jQuery('#myTabContent .adminform').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery('#myTabContent .adminform').css('visibility','visible');
        }
    }

    // Initial pageload check
    checkStatus();

});

EOF;
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in my testing :)  I just want to remove the editor.  Which then meant I needed to change the category from `span3` to `span12`.  However, although I did manage to get the tab to disappear using `if ($this->item->catid == 14):` so I'm halfway there.  The close button stopped working though.  My efforts continue.

Comment: The close button my not work if you hide the editor via `display:none` or by removing it from DOM (I have a faint memory I had a similar issue one time). I added a proof-of-concept to my answer. Give it a go; it worked for me.

Comment: wow!  That's fantastic.  I'll give that a go now.  I think I will allow users to add the category part but that's a small amendment.  I'll repost my code when done.  Or post a link to an installable zip.

Comment: Drew, if I make this plugin, would you mind if I released it in the JED?  Obviously it's not my work so I wouldn't charge for it but I think others would find this useful.

Comment: Go for it! You can give me credit somewhere for the original code if you want and remove the "cm_" from the name (that's a prefix I use for my own extensions) but otherwise have at it.

Comment: Certainly will give you credit.  Will make some tweaks too :)  What does CM stand for?  And also if you can let me know how you want your attribution, any links etc

Comment: Hmm, when I tried this I get `Fatal error: Cannot declare class plg_XXX, because the name is already in use in /home/xxx/xxx/plugins/editors-xtd/plg_xxx/plg_xxx.php on line 0`

Comment: Actually now I think about it, what I want is to use a field as an editor but it doesn't have read more in it.  So what I really need is to have the original editor as a field.  and then detect if it exists and remove the old editor.  This is getting complicated.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by "use a field as an editor but it doesn't have read more in it" or "have the original editor as a field". Could you reiterate?

Comment: in Joomla! custom fields you can choose "editor" as one of the fields.  But if you do there is no read more option.  Thus, it will not work with a blog view.  So I need to move the editor from the content tab to the fields tab.  It seems like quite a complex job and I'm not sure you can just move the editor to a new tab like that.  In any case I think this is something that would be really useful when making custom views as users find it hard to understand fields in one tab and content in another especially if not in order

Comment: "I'm not sure you can just move the editor to a new tab like that." You can since all tab content is loaded on the initial page load. However, that'll create other issues so it would probably be better to just make a new editor in that tab. If the "Joomla! Custom Fields" method doesn't work because of the lack of a read-more option then you should still be able to do it "the old way", by adding `JFactory::getEditor()->display()` code to the appropriate layout file (for the tab you want) in `/administrator/templates/<tpl>/html/layouts/joomla/edit/<target-tab>.php`

Comment: I haven't used needed to use any of the "Joomla! Custom Fields" yet but in the documentation `https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Editor_Field` their editor has the read more link. It may just be an issue of configuration for you. I'd look into that first before attempting to move the content editor or injecting an editor using the pre-Custom Fields method (that I mentioned in my last comment).

Comment: In which case if the editor would work I'd still need to remove the original editor.  But I get that Fatal error.

Comment: That fatal error seems to indicate that whatever you named the plugin is the same name as another already installed plugin. You should be able to fix it by simply renaming the plugin to something else.